# How to Capture Notification for database trigger executed?

Tags: php, mysql, database, triggers

My application modifies row in table  foo, which subsequently  invokes trigger. Is there way my application  can know about trigger executed or not?

Comment: Is there any reason you need to know the trigger has run, if the trigger is correct and properly tested it should be reliable enough to just let it get on with it's job.

Comment: My application has event bus (say no. of likes) which update user's score, if they match some constraint, they fire activity and engagement score levels. I wish to know if activity score changes or not. Right now i am just comparing pre-data and post-data comparison, which is extremely bulky,error-prone at application level.

Answer (score 0):

Can you give some more details? What does the trigger do? Theoretically you can just tell your application to check if the action that was executed by the trigger made or not. Another solution is creating a table that documents triggers, make a trigger to the same action in foo table but this time make it write a row in a "trigger_log" table for example and then you will be able to check if it executed or not.

Comment: nice idea. I used change data capture (size on aws is killing my nerves )and sql scripts , still just curious for other possible-elegant solution.